# Tabelas Relacionais de Pedidos em C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Bom dia Pessoal, estou desenvolvendo uma tela de pedidos onde serão adicionados produtos para compor a requisição, porém não consigo imaginar uma forma de salvar os itens do pedido em uma tabela, como poderia relacionar a tabela do cadastro do produto com a tabela da requisição ?

estou usando o sql server e estou programando em C# no visual studio

Comment: Você pode adicionar seus produtos a um `DataGridView` ou `ListView`, depois através das `Rows` coletar dados para armazenamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira coisa a se fazer, é criar as tabelas, no caso você teria as tabelas `Produto`, `Pedido` e a tabela de relacionamento `PedidoProduto`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Produtos (
    ProdutoId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL rowguidcol default newsequentialid(),
    Descricao varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Produtos ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Produtos PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProdutoId) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Pedidos (
    PedidoId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL rowguidcol default newsequentialid(),
    Descricao varchar(50) NOT NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Pedidos ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Pedidos PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PedidoId) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.PedidoProdutos (
    PedidoProdutoLinkId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL rowguidcol default newsequentialid(),
    PedidoId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ProdutoId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    Quantidade decimal(10, 2) NOT NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.PedidoProdutos ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PedidoProdutos PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PedidoProdutoLinkId) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Neste momento não existe relacionamento entre as tabelas, você precisa criar um relacionamento de `1:N` entre `Pedido` e `PedidoProduto` e `N:1` entre `PedidoProduto` e `Produto`. Na pratica será um relacionamento de `N:M` entre `Produto` e `Pedido`.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.PedidoProdutos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PedidoProdutos_Pedidos 
FOREIGN KEY (PedidoId) REFERENCES dbo.Pedidos (PedidoId) 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
ON DELETE  NO ACTION
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.PedidoProdutos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PedidoProdutos_Produtos 
FOREIGN KEY (ProdutoId) REFERENCES dbo.Produtos (ProdutoId) 
ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
ON DELETE  NO ACTION    
GO
```

E claro, não esqueça de criar os índices para as FK (apesar de não ser obrigatório).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PedidoProdutos_ProdutoId ON dbo.PedidoProdutos(ProdutoId) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PedidoProdutos_PedidoId_ProdutoId ON dbo.PedidoProdutos(PedidoId, ProdutoId) on [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Agora vamos ao C#, então vamos modelar as entidades.:

```
public class Produto
{
    public Guid ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PedidoProduto> Pedidos { get; set; }
}

public class Pedido
{
    public Guid PedidoId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PedidoProduto> Produtos { get; set; }
}

public class PedidoProduto
{
    public Guid PedidoProdutoId { get; set; }
    public Guid PedidoId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantidade { get; set; }

    public Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
    public Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

caso não esteja utilizando um ORM para inserir os dados, aconselho que venha a utilizar o [`Dapper`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) e [`Dapper.Contrib`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib): `Install-Package Dapper` e `Install-Package Dapper.Contrib`, e neste caso em especifico, já que a Chave é uma Guid, use o [`RT.Comb`](https://github.com/richardtallent/RT.Comb): `Install-Package RT.Comb`

segue abaixo um exemplo para inserir um Produto.:

```
var produto = new Produto
{
    ProdutoId = RT.Comb.Provider.Sql.Create(),
    Descricao = "Produto 01"
};

using (var conexao = new SqlConnection("%sua string de conexao%"))
{
    conexao.Open();
    conexao.Insert(produto);
}
```

agora vamos ao `Pedido` e os seus respectivos `Produtos`

```
var pedido = new Pedido
{
    PedidoId = RT.Comb.Provider.Sql.Create(),
    Descricao = "Pedido 01",
    Produtos = new List<PedidoProduto>()
};

for (var i = 1, i <= 5, i++)
{
    var produtoId = Guid.Parse("%id do produto aqui%");
    var produto = new PedidoProduto
    {
        PedidoProdutoId = RT.Comb.Provider.Sql.Create(),
        PedidoId = pedido.PedidoId,
        ProdutoId = produtoId,
        Quantidade = i
    };
    pedido.Produtos.Add(produto)
}

using (var conexao = new SqlConnection("%sua string de conexao%"))
{
    conexao.Open();
    using (var tras = conexao.BeginTransaction())
    {
        conexao.Insert(pedido);
        foreach (var produto in pedido.Produtos)
        {
            conexao.Insert(produto);
        }
        tras.Commit();
    }
}
```

E por fim, caso queria realizar uma consulta.:

```
var pedidoId = Guid.Parse("%id do pedido aqui%");
using (var conexao = new SqlConnection("%sua string de conexao%"))
{
    conexao.Open();
    var pedido = conexao.QueryFirstOrDefault<Pedido>("SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE PedidoId = @PedidoId", new { PedidoId = pedidoId });
    pedido.Produtos = conexao.Query<PedidoProduto>("SELECT * FROM PedidoProdutos WHERE PedidoId = @PedidoId", new { PedidoId = pedidoId }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado tobias